# I am getting A Problem in Python It's Not A Error But It's Not Working As I Wanted

Tags: python

import random

while True:

```
x = input("What Is Your Name ? : ") 
a = ["Topper", "Loser", "Average"]

if x == ("Krish", "krish"):
    print("Krish Is Topper")

elif x == ("Gazal", "gazal"):
    print("Gazal Is Loser")
    
elif x == (" "):
    print("Please Enter A Name")
    
elif x == type(float):
    print("Please Enter A Name")

elif x != ("Krish", "krish", "gazal", "Gazal"):
    print((x ) + (" ") + ("Is ") + ("a") + (" ") + (random.choice(a)))
```

I Wanted The Solution To Print Topper If I Type "Krish" or "krish" And If I type "Gazal" Or "gazal" It should Print Loser. And If The Input Is Anything else rather than "Krish", "krish", "gazal" or "Gazal" It Should randomly Choose One from The "A" List. But its Not Working Please Can Anybody Check it And Ensure It.

Comment: *The Code " "import random" And "While True:" Is Not Coming In the code Section"*

Comment: `in/not in`, not `==/!=`. A `str` value will never be *equal* to a `tuple` value, but the tuple may *contain* the `str` value.

Comment: `input` always returns a `str`, so `x` will *never* be the `float` type (or be an instance of `float`).

Comment: `==` is not doing what you expect.  For instance, you want `x in ("Krish", "krish")` rather than x == ("Krish", "krish")` to check if x is "krish" or "Krish".  Alternately, use `x.lower() == "krish"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import random
alist = ['Topper', 'Loser', 'Average']
names = {'krish': alist[0], 'gazal': alist[1]}
name = input('What is your name? ')
if (nickname := names.get(name.lower(), None)):
    print(f'{name} is {nickname}')
else:
    print(random.choice(alist))
```